# Jenkins Gradle Plugin is not using the local maven repository

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build Android Gradle project with Jenkins. The Gradle build fails to locate the required dependencies. I have maven repository at `~/.m2/repository` path. However the Gradle build is looking the dependencies at `/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository` location. This should ideally lookup at `~/.m2/repository` which is the default path for local repository.

Following is my Gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.1'
}
repositories {
    def androidHome = System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")
    maven { url "$androidHome/extras/android/m2repository/" }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

The Jenkins build fails with following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':myapp.base.module'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':myapp.dependency.module'.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':myapp.dependency.module:_debugCompile'.
      > Could not find org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.1.
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/pawan/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.0.1/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.1.pom
            file:/home/pawan/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.0.1/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.1.jar
            file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.0.1/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.1.pom
            file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.0.1/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.1.jar
            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.0.1/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.1.pom
            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.0.1/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.1.jar
            file:/home/pawan/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.0.1/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.1.pom
            file:/home/pawan/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.0.1/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.1.jar
        Required by:
            build-gradle-projects:myapp.dependency.module:unspecified
```

I find it strange that the exception shows that Gradle is looking in the `/var/lib/jenkins/.m2` to find the dependency: `org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.1`.

I confirm that the path does not exists.

Comment: To diagnose a Gradle build problem, we would have to see the Gradle build script.

Comment: The script works on CL and from Android studio. The prob is it is using wrong directory when run via Jenkins.

Comment: That's great. I'll say it again, if you don't show us anything, there's nothing anyone can to do to help you.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Apologies. I have updated the question with the Gradle build script and the output.

Comment: @Pawan Have you found the solution?